# Parsing pro rata temporis

Tags: idiom, translation-explanation

Recently when reading some material related to research grants, I came across the Latin phrase *pro rata temporis* in English text.
It was easy enough to understand in the context.
For example, a 600 000 € grant might be for three years, and if one applies for a shorter period of time, the maximum money is reduced *pro rata temporis*, so that for two years one can get at most 400 000 €.

But how do I parse the Latin phrase?
I have difficulties seeing how it could mean what it does.
Is the phrase an abbreviation of something longer?
Does it have an origin that would help me understand how it works?
Would the phrase make sense in classical Latin without context?
I take it that *rata* is a perfect participle of [*reri*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=reor&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), and L&S lists under II.B.1 *pro rata parte/portione*, which makes me think that perhaps an ablative like *parte* or *portione* is implied.

Comment: The phrase I'm familiar with for this practice is "pro-rating", which seems to come from the Latin expression?

Comment: @Draconis Apparently so, although it sounds more like "professional rating" to me at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *parte* or *portione* is understood here; sometimes it's explicit.

*OLD* has a separate entry for the adjective *ratus* (in origin, the perfect participle of *reor*). Definition 3 is 'Determined, fixed, certain,' and definition 3b is as follows (bold added for emphasis):

> *~a pars*, a fixed proportion; esp. *pro ~a parte* (*portione*), in proportion; **also *pro ~a* alone**.

One attestation is *CIL* 2.5181.27 (from Hispania), which actually uses the phrase *pro rata temporis* (without *parte* or *portione*):

> EIUS TEMPORIS PRO RATA PENSIONEM CONDUCTOR REPUTARE DEBETO